# Rename character value in R data.table based on condition in another column

Tags: r, data.table

I simply want to rename a character value based on a condition in another character column in data.table using R.

example: if dt$code== "J1234B" make dt$codename= "Drug1".

Both columns are characters.

I am an R novice and seem to be having great difficulty doing this, can anyone help?

Comment: Th proper data.table syntax would be `dt[code ==  "J1234B", codename := "Drug1"]`. Please read some data.table vignettes such as [this](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you ask is something like this:

```
library(data.table)
a = data.table(a = 'a', b = 'b')
a[a == 'a']
   a b
1: a b

a[a == 'a']$b = 'c'

> a
   a b
1: a c
```

In the example, we have a data.table with 2 columns, a and b, and I searched all entries in column a whose value is 'a' and rename its second column (b) to 'c'

Using your example would be:

```
dt[code == "J1234B"]$codename= "Drug1"
```

Comment: Thanks for this Leo, very helpful indeed! I have just run the code as suggested but it seems to have went slightly wrong so I am double-checking what I have done- I may have made a mistake somehow.

Comment: Hi Leo, I have tried again and this has worked great!! Much obliged for your help on this!!!!

Comment: `a[a == 'a', b := 'c']` would be the standard syntax.